# How does the python listing functions like os.listdir() work?

Tags: python, list, python-os, directory-listing

I am trying to understand how the underlying process differs if I call the os.listdir() function as compared to running ls in the terminal.

After much searching, I came across these 2 keypoints
GNU ls waits until all entries are fetched before returning any of them.
Python listing functions do not necessarily invoke GNU ls.

So,I want to find out if the python listing functions also exhibit similar behavior like waiting for all entries before returning any of them or return the entries as received.

Comment: “Python listing functions do not necessarily invoke GNU ls” — No, they *definitely* don’t invoke `ls`.

Comment: os.listdir doesn't invoke ls, they just both use the same C function to do the operation (python's os.listdir is implemented in C https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/posixmodule.c#L4308-L4342). After using that POSIX function, ls does the sorting by default - you can use -f flag to disable the sorting and get the order the underlying C function returned - it will be the same order as os.listdir returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` cannot return entries as it reads them. `return` doesn't work like that - a function can only return once, and it ends as soon as it returns. `os.listdir` returns a list of names, and it cannot add more data to that list after it returns.

For `os.listdir` to not output all its data at once, it would have to be designed differently. For example, it could return an iterator (like [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) does), and the iterator could read one directory entry on every iteration. Or it could return a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) and start a background thread that reads directory entries and `put`s their names on the queue one by one.

`os.listdir` was not designed like that. It was designed to read directory entries, put their names in a list, and return that list.

Comment: So are there paginated calls involved to read directory entries ?
I want to know that before putting the names of dir in the list,what happens? All entries being fetched first before putting in a list or keep on appending to that list as entries are received and return after all entries have been fetched.

Comment: @newbie: I do have an answer to that question, but first, why are you asking? There's no way that implementation detail would ever matter to any code that uses `os.listdir`, but it sounds like you're expecting it to matter somehow.

Comment: I want to verify this behavior whether or not paginated calls are involved for fetching directory entries when using python listing functions.

Comment: So... you're wondering whether it makes a single call to some underlying API that returns all directory entries at once, or if it makes multiple underlying calls that each return partial data?

Comment: Yes.This was what I meant to ask initially. Specifically for os.listdir()

Comment: It makes multiple underlying calls, either to [`readdir`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Modules/posixmodule.c#L4197) or to [`FindNextFileW`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Modules/posixmodule.c#L4103) depending on the OS. Those functions fetch data on a single directory entry. I don't know if an underlying API to get all the directory contents at once actually exists.